# JSON data not showing on SFchart! Syncfusion

Tags: json, xamarin, charts, syncfusion

HELP!!!

So ive spent days and hours trying to just get my data to show on a sfchart however either it wont display anything on the page or it just displays the axis and not the actual data,

- i am deserializing JSON data binding it to the sf chart

I have created Tabs that either display the graph in XML code or C# code yet i have not gotten either to work.
If you could please let me know what im doing wrong i will try copy and paste as much of the code on here

Xaml Main Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Drip" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  x:Class="Drip.DripPage">


    <ContentPage Title= "Data Log">
                 <StackLayout>
                     <ListView x:Name="postsListView" HasUnevenRows="true" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing='Handle_Refreshing'>
                         <ListView.Header>
                             <StackLayout  Orientation= "Horizontal" Padding="20,10,0,10" BackgroundColor="#88CCF1">
                                <Label Text="Entries" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                             <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                 <Label Text="Litres Used " HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                                 <Label Text="Date/Time  " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                         </ListView.Header>
                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                         <ColumnDefinition Width= "0.5*"/>
                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>                             
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Entry_id}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Field1}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Created_at}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                               </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>


    <local:MyPage Title="Chart"/>


    <ContentPage Title= "Guage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <local:RootObject></local:RootObject>

    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

     <chart:SfChart>

   <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

        <chart:CategoryAxis>

            <chart:CategoryAxis.Title>

                  <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Date"> </chart:ChartAxisTitle>

            </chart:CategoryAxis.Title>

         </chart:CategoryAxis>

   </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

   <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

       <chart:NumericalAxis>

           <chart:NumericalAxis.Title>

                 <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Amount of Water Used (in Litres)"></chart:ChartAxisTitle>

          </chart:NumericalAxis.Title>      

      </chart:NumericalAxis>   

     </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

      <chart:SfChart.Series>

         <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Feeds}" XBindingPath="Created_at" YBindingPath="Field1">

         </chart:ColumnSeries>

      </chart:SfChart.Series>

 </chart:SfChart>






    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Code behind Main Page

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Drip
{


    public partial class DripPage : TabbedPage
    {
        void Handle_Refreshing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            postsListView.ItemsSource = _data;
            postsListView.EndRefresh();
        }

        private const string Url = "https://thingspeak.com/channels/301726/field/1.json";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<Feed> _data;


        public DripPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

            _data = new ObservableCollection<Feed>(data.Feeds.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created_at));
            postsListView.ItemsSource = _data;




            base.OnAppearing();
        }

    }
}
```

c# splineSeries chart on code behind then referenced in main xaml

```
sing Newtonsoft.Json;
using Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Drip;

namespace ChartGettingStarted
{

    public class RootObject
    {

        public List<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Feed
    {
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
        public int Entry_id { get; set; }
        public decimal Field1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DripPage : ContentPage
    {
        private const string Url = "https://thingspeak.com/channels/301726/field/1.json";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<Feed> _data;


        SfChart chart;
        SplineSeries series;

        public DripPage()
        {
            chart = new SfChart();

            CategoryAxis primaryAxis = new CategoryAxis();

            chart.PrimaryAxis = primaryAxis;

            //Initializing Secondary Axis
            NumericalAxis secondaryAxis = new NumericalAxis();

            chart.SecondaryAxis = secondaryAxis;
            series = new SplineSeries();
            Content = chart;
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
            _data = new ObservableCollection<Feed>(data.Feeds);

            series.ItemsSource = _data;
            series.XBindingPath = "Created_at";
            series.YBindingPath = "Field1";
            chart.Series.Add(series);

            base.OnAppearing();
        }


    }
}
```

models

```
namespace Drip
{
    public class RootObject
    {

        public List<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

namespace Drip

```
{
    public class Feed
    {
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
        public int Entry_id { get; set; }
        public decimal Field1 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Drip
{
    public class Channel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated_at { get; set; }
        public string Elevation { get; set; }
        public int Last_entry_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: you have two different classes called DripPage - one is a TabbedPage and one is a ContentPage, each in different namespaces?  I don't see anything that makes me think the DripPage code-behind with the chart logic is ever called.  I'd really suggest you get rid of the multiple pages and just create a single simple ContentPage with a chart on it.  Once you get that working you can add additional pages.

Comment: Ahh my bad i got the content page from syncfusion was trying to integrate it into the app.

Comment: Thing is if i make a single simple content page how can i call json data to go to my list view and to the chart if the json data is on the content page. Quite new to xamarin so still dont know much

Comment: The xaml file with the column series only shows the axis and not the data, could you help me find a solution for that?

Comment: Ok fixed everything and works now thanks heaps for pointing that out Jason!

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your code snippet, and you are missing to set the collection values for binding context instance and not inherited by INotifyPropertyChanged interface of RootObject Class. We have modified the sample as per your requirement. Please find the attached sample from the below link.

[SimpleSample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ChartGettingStarted1689619843)

Please let us know, if you have further assistance on this.